# How do I know if an element is in the lower 20 % of the screen?

Tags: prototypejs, prototype

Is there a way to figure out, if an element (like a div) is visible in the lower 20% of the screen using Prototype? I dont know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements properly (your box would have its bottom at or above the bottom of the visible screen, and its top at or below the 80% of the visible screen) then this is how you would go about this.

The visible screen is calculated by taking `document.viewport.getScrollOffsets()['top']`, and then subtracting 80% of `document.viewport.getHeight()` to get your other bounds. Your element is polled during the window#scroll event, and checked for its position with `viewportOffset()` (this returns the position of the top-left corner), and the height of the element would be used for the rest.

```
Event.observe(window, 'scroll', check_offsets);
Event.observe(window, 'load', check_offsets);
function check_offsets(){
  var e = $('spy');
  var top = e.viewportOffset()['top'];
  var bottom = top + e.getHeight();
  var scroll = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets()['top'];
  var scroll_80 = scroll - parseInt(document.viewport.getHeight() * .8, 10);
  if(bottom <= scroll) console.log('visible');
  if(top <= scroll_80) console.log('too high')
}
```